# Join two tables and show distinct records

Tags: ms-access, join

I have two tables in MS Access 2010:

PART LOG-OUT TABLE:

```
PART_ID DRAWN_DATE LOCATION_ID
 C0001  07/29/2013     501
 C0002  07/29/2013     604
 C0003  08/01/2013     703
 C0004  08/01/2013     807
 C0005  08/02/2013     505
 C0006  08/02/2013     602
 C0007  08/02/2013     707
 C0008  08/03/2013     802
 C0009  08/03/2013     803
 C0001  10/01/2013     605
 C0002  10/02/2013     704
 C0004  10/05/2013     806
```

PART RETURN TABLE:

```
PART_ID RETURN_DATE LOCATION_ID
 C0001  09/04/2013     STORE
 C0002  09/05/2013     STORE
 C0004  09/10/2013     STORE
 C0007  09/12/2013     STORE
 C0008  09/13/2013     STORE
 C0002  10/03/2013     STORE
```

This is the result I want:

```
PART_ID DRAWN_DATE LOG-OUT LOCATION RETURN_DATE RETURN LOCATION
 C0001  07/29/2013       501        09/04/2013       STORE
 C0001  10/01/2013       605
 C0002  07/29/2013       604        09/05/2013       STORE
 C0002  10/02/2013       704        10/03/2013       STORE
 C0003  08/01/2013       703
 C0004  08/01/2013       807        09/10/2013       STORE
 C0004  10/05/2013       806        
 C0005  08/02/2013       505
 C0006  08/02/2013       602
 C0007  08/02/2013       707        09/13/2013       STORE
 C0008  08/03/2013       802        10/03/2013       STORE
 C0009  08/03/2013       803
```

But I can only get this:

```
PART_ID DRAWN_DATE LOG-OUT LOCATION RETURN_DATE RETURN LOCATION
 C0001  07/29/2013       501        09/04/2013       STORE
 C0001  10/01/2013       605        `09/04/2013       STORE`
 C0002  07/29/2013       604        09/05/2013       STORE
 `C0002  07/29/2013       604`        10/03/2013       STORE
 C0002  10/02/2013       704        `09/05/2013       STORE`
 `C0002  10/02/2013       704        10/03/2013       STORE`
 C0003  08/01/2013       703
 C0004  08/01/2013       807        09/10/2013       STORE
 C0004  10/05/2013       806        `09/10/2013       STORE`
 C0005  08/02/2013       505
 C0006  08/02/2013       602
 C0007  08/02/2013       707        09/13/2013       STORE
 C0008  08/03/2013       802        10/03/2013       STORE
 C0009  08/03/2013       803
```

after I wrote:

`SELECT L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, L.LOCATION_ID AS [LOG-OUT LOCATION], R.RETURN_DATE, R.LOCATION_ID AS RETURN_LOCATION FROM (SELECT * FROM [PART LOG-OUT] ORDER BY PART_ID) AS L LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [PART RETURN] ORDER BY PART_ID) AS R ON L.PART_ID = R.PART_ID ORDER BY L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, R.RETURN_DATE;`

Can somebody correct me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit vague so I may be off, but you seem to want to pair returns with times that are before the return only, something like this?

```
SELECT L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, L.LOCATION_ID AS [LOG-OUT LOCATION], 
       MIN(R.RETURN_DATE), MIN(R.LOCATION_ID) AS RETURN_LOCATION 
FROM (SELECT * FROM [LOG_OUT LOCATION]) AS L 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [PART_RETURN]) AS R 
  ON L.PART_ID = R.PART_ID AND L.DRAWN_DATE < R.RETURN_DATE
GROUP BY L.LOCATION_ID,L.PART_ID,L.DRAWN_DATE
ORDER BY L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, MIN(R.RETURN_DATE)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31eeb/3).

Note that since there's nothing pairing a single purchase with a single return (and no such sample in your question), the logic is very basic for pairing them up.

Comment: After some amendments,  SELECT L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, L.LOCATION_ID AS [LOG-OUT LOCATION], 
           MIN(R.RETURN_DATE), MIN(R.LOCATION_ID) AS RETURN_LOCATION 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM [PART LOG-OUT]) AS L 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [PART RETURN]) AS R 
      ON L.PART_ID = R.PART_ID AND L.DRAWN_DATE < R.RETURN_DATE
    GROUP BY L.LOCATION_ID,L.PART_ID,L.DRAWN_DATE
    ORDER BY L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, MIN(R.RETURN_DATE)

Answer (score 0):

As you are joining on the `PART_ID` column, the result you are getting is what you would expect to get.

For example, there are two `C0001` in the `LOG-OUT` table and these will join to the same `C0001` in the `PART RETURN` table as there is nothing to distringuish the rows in the return table from each other:

```
PART LOG-OUT TABLE         -> PART RETURN TABLE
C0001  07/29/2013     501  -> C0001  09/04/2013     STORE
C0001  10/01/2013     605  -> C0001  09/04/2013     STORE
```

You need another criteria to join on, or you need to join on some more unique identifier in order to achieve the results you are looking for.

Comment: If `C0001,07/29/2013,501` should be joined and `C0001,10/01/2013,605` should not be, you need to find a way to distinguish between the two.  Based on the table structure you have shown I cannot see a way to achieve it, because there is no way to know which `C0001` you should join to in the `PART RETURN TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, L.LOCATION_ID AS [LOG-OUT LOCATION], R.RETURN_DATE, R.LOCATION_ID AS RETURN_LOCATION FROM (SELECT * FROM [PART LOG-OUT] ORDER BY PART_ID) AS L LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [PART RETURN] ORDER BY PART_ID) AS R ON L.PART_ID = R.PART_ID ORDER BY L.PART_ID, L.DRAWN_DATE, R.RETURN_DATE;
```

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN will be converted into LEFT JOIN after the program run.